# Elantouchpad not working on Hp laptop with any distro

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, touchpad, hp

So i have an HP Pavillion 15 Gaming laptop on which I recently tried to install ubuntu. But the main problem that i faced was that the touchpad wouldn't work at all.
I switched over to pop os and manjaro and in both of them the touchpad was working fine in the live environment but after installation, it stopped working again in both of em.
Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please try Fedora 35

Comment: First of all, please include what exact model of touchpad you are using. You should be able to find it with `lsusb`. Second, by "it stopped working" do you mean that it worked at some point? Also: is there any F button on your keyboard for dis-/enabling the touchpad?

Comment: @mashuptwice the touchpad is not being detected at all therefore lsusb isnt showing anything related to the touchpad

Comment: @Destrexx Without knowing what touchpad you are using or any other information it is unlikely that anybody can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue for pop os. Solution to not working touchpad on pop os was:

```
sudo kernelstub -a "i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
```

Pop os use kernelstub instead of grub

https://support.system76.com/articles/kernelstub/

what i8042.nopnp=1 mean

```
i8042.nopnp [HW] Don't use ACPIPnP / PnPBIOS to discover KBD/AUX
                 controllers
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with HP pavilion 15.

according to this link https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,1666.0.html

I tried these three methods:

**first method:**

```
sudo su
nano /etc/default/grub
```

insert "`psmouse.proto=bare`" in line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.proto=bare"
```

then update grub (you can replace `fedora` by your distro name like `ubuntu`)

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

or

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

and reboot.

**second method:**

```
  sudo su
  nano /etc/default/grub
```

insert "`psmouse.proto=imps i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1`" in line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.proto=imps i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1"
```

then update grub (you can replace `fedora` by your distro name like `ubuntu`)

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

or

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

and reboot.

**third method:**

```
sudo su
echo -n 0x01 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/crc_enabled
```

or

```
echo -n 0x01 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/crc_enabled
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, none of these worked, and so this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One wired solution that I found was that if you stop the system to boot directly to GRUB and instead of that if you just press the key that loads up the boot selector of your bios(in my case F9), the problem just did not occur. And apart from that on a pure arch installation I didn't even need to do that.